# Spring shell 2.0 how to read inputs with mask

Tags: spring-shell

Is there any way to mask user inputs in Spring Shell 2.0.x ?

I need to collect password from user.. did not find any shell api to do that.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that LineReader#readLine(msg,mask) provides that option.

All you have to do is inject the LineReader bean.

Comment: try autowirting with  `@lazy`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on third party libraries, you can always do a standard Java console input, something like:

```
private String inputPassword() {
  Console console = System.console();
  return new String(console.readPassword());
}
```

Note though that when running this in an IDE, the System.console() might be null. So you should probably handle that if running in an IDE is something you want to support (for testing for example..) something like:

```
private String inputPassword() {
    Console console = System.console();
    // Console can be null when running in an IDE
    if (console == null) {
        System.out.println("WARNING - CAN'T HIDE PASSWORD");
        return new Scanner(System.in).next();
    }

    return new String(console.readPassword());
}
```